# How can I get all streets width of Paris

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, streets

I'm trying to query OpenStreetMap via QGIS (for example) to get a list of all streets in Paris and their width.

example :

1. Boulevard Sebastopol : 30m
2. Rue Tiquetonne : 11m
3. etc

Is there such data in OpenStreetMap ? or anywhere else ?

Comment: By the "width of the street", do you mean mean the distance between the  buildings on either side of the street? If so [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/206627/55203) is similar. (OSM has very good coverage for buildings in Paris)

Comment: Yes the distance between buildings. I would love to consider the variable width along a street but it will be too complex to handle (as I want to color the street depending on its width). I will first try to get all "average" or minimum width of every street. Thanks for your reply, I will check this answer !

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap data is not really setup like that.  If you're familiar with editing OSM you will know that to create a road it is a simple line. So any road width that is styled is purely for the style of the map and not an actual account of the width of the roads.

Having said that you may get lucky with a crazy OSM fanatic who might have gone around the streets and measured them to add a tag with the width data (highly unlikely).

Suggestion I can think of would be to:

1. Download Paris from [geofabrik.de](http://www.geofabrik.de). This will at least give you the OSM data and all the related information.
2. Check the French highway agency to see what information they have on on their types of roads.  It may that they have a standard widths for varying road uses.  This way you can create a CSV and join it to the different OSM road types.
3. And by far the worst suggestion would be to use google earth or something and measure the widths. Then apply those measurements to similar roads.

Comment: This is not entirely true since OSM has a [width](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width) key. See my answer.

Comment: I understand and I have tried (poorly it seems) to suggest that the OSM data can hold the width information, but only if it's provided at time of creation, or through an edit.  Both suggestions in your answer have been covered in my answer: The use of the width key is only useful if the "beloved OSM fanatic" has added the tag. It is not something automatically created with the data.  And your second extends my point 2, as the highway key would be what the questioner needs to relate what information he can find about road widths from the French highway authorities.

Comment: Yes, I will have a look first at the OSM data. I could get lucky because it  is Paris, it may not be the case for other locations :) Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I have downloaded the data from  geofabrik.de, I searched in all attributes tables of all layers but couldn't find a key named 'width'. I am new with all GIS stuff so maybe I am not searching the right place ? Can you help me through this please ?

Comment: Then I'm afraid that information doesn't exist in OSM.  Remember OSM is free opensource, and built by the general public. So the information provided is only what people have felt like adding.  But that data is still useful.  Like using the 'Highway' key in scai's answer.  Now you will either have to hunt for width data through french construction or policy documents and join that data to the OSM highway key, or measure the roads yourself (with google) and again join that data.  It's not the end of the road yet ;)

Comment: haha yeah thanks :)
I'll keep you posted anyways. If I ever get all this data I will gladly add it to OSM

Answer (score 2):

The width of a road (or other feature) in OSM can be specified with the [width](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width) key. However most roads in OSM don't have this key. If the width key is not present then you can try to estimate the width using the road class ([highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) key) and the number of [lanes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes), if available.

Comment: Streets don't have a single width. You can have an average width or you can sample the width at regular intervals to gain s more accurate picture. More useful is the number of lanes.

Comment: This depends on the street. A street in OSM can consist of more than a single [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) and thus can have multiple width tags, one for each way it consists of.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is! The data is in the polygons do you can mix with the streets and have the size

https://opendata.paris.fr/explore/dataset/plan-de-voirie-chaussees/map/?disjunctive.num_pave&location=18,48.85728,2.31858&basemap=jawg.streets